# Check generic Array for empty (default) fields

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I have a generic `Array2D` class and want to add an `isEmpty` getter. However `T` cannot be compared with `default(T)` via `!=` in this case. And `Equals()` cannot be used since the field might be `null` (but see code below). How would I be able to check whether all fields are empty (i.e. the default value for the reference type or struct/etc.) or not?

So far I came up with the following solution but it already seems rather long-winded to me for a simple `isEmpty` check and it might not be the optimal way to solve this. Anyone know of a better solution?

```
public sealed class Array2D<T>
{
    private T[,] _fields;
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public bool isEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
                {
                    if (_fields[x, y] != null && !_fields[x, y].Equals(default(T))) return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Array2D(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width < 0 ? 0 : width;
        _height = height < 0 ? 0 : height;
        _fields = new T[width, height];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is another way (in terms of performance): you still have to go through each element. Maybe you can do a "foreach" to replace those two "for"s and put that iteration in another method.

Comment: If performance of this particular check is important simply check for assignment of non-default value  in you "indexer" (however you've implemented "set element at [i,j]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through all of the elements in `IsEmpty`, simply update the value of `IsEmpty` when setting a value (requires an indexer but you'll probably need one anyway) :

```
public class Array2<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] _array;
    private bool _isEmpty;

    public Array2(int width, int height)
    {
        _array = new T[width, height];
        _isEmpty = true;
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return _array[x, y]; }
        set
        {
            _array[x, y] = value;
            _isEmpty = _isEmpty && value.Equals(default(T));
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return _isEmpty; }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Array2<int> array2 = new Array2<int>(10, 10);
array2[0, 0] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(array2.IsEmpty);
array2[0, 0] = 1;
Console.WriteLine(array2.IsEmpty);
array2[0, 0] = 0;
Console.WriteLine(array2.IsEmpty);
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
```

Obviously this is a trade-off, but imagine that you have 1 million elements in the array, your loop runs 1 million times. With this approach there's no loop, only checking for 2 conditions at any time.

Comment: Thanks! That would work in most cases. For now in the mean time I had to make the class IEnmmerable  so I implemented the enumeration code according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee5kxzk0(v=vs.90).aspx ... So I replaced above with a foreach loop depending on the enumerator. Still a loop but then again in my code the array is never really that big.